# Changing bullet direction based on the way player is facing

Tags: javascript, game-physics

I am making a little platformer.I am able to make the player shoot to the right, but when I try to make it shoot in the direction the player is "facing", turn the other way, the bullets change their direction too, here's my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vux123/9uhjjvxe/)

```
if(keys[13] &&Date.now()-lastFire>100){

    bullets.push({
        x:player.x,
        y:player.y,
        });

    lastFire = Date.now();
}
for (var i=0;i<bullets.length;i++){

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(bullets[i].x,bullets[i].y,2,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fill();
    if(facingRight & !facingLeft ){
        bullets[i].x+=10;
    }
    else if(!facingRight & facingLeft ){
        bullets[i].x-=10;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are updating the position of all the bullets based on the direction the player is facing. If you want to preserve the direction in which each bullet is heading, you have to store it for each bullet.

Store a change in position (`dx`)when the bullet is created:

```
bullets.push({
  x: player.x,
  y: player.y,
  dx: facingLeft ? -10 : 10
})
```

Draw and update all the bullets using:

```
bullets.forEach(function (bullet) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  cts.arc(bullet.x, bullet.y, 2, 0, Math.PI*2);
  ctx.fill();
  bullet.x += bullet.dx
})
```

Note: You are using `&`, the bitwise and operator instead of `&&` which you probably ment to use.

Note 2: You should probably store the direction the player is facing in a single variable:

```
var LEFT = 1
var RIGHT = 2
var playerFacing = LEFT
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but it didn't work for me, the game freezes when I try to shoot.

Comment: Haha sorry I forgot, Here you go :D